# module path lost in multiprocessing spawn (ModuleNotFoundError)

Tags: python, path, multiprocessing

Say we have a script that works with no problem:

```
import module1

class SomeClass(object):
   def __init__(self):
      self.m = module1()

s = SomeCLass()
```

However if I use multiprocessing module with "spawn" context:

```
import module1
import multiprocessing as mp

class SomeClass(object):
   def __init__(self):
      self.m = module1()

s = SomeCLass()
ctx = mp.get_context('spawn')
proc = ctx.Process(target=SomeClass, kwargs={})
proc.daemon = True
proc.start()
```

I get the following error at `proc.start()`:

```
   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'module1'
```

Yet, if I add the following lines before "import modlule1":

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, path_to_module1)

import module1
import multiprocessing as mp

class SomeClass(object):
   def __init__(self):
      self.m = module1()

s = SomeCLass()
ctx = mp.get_context('spawn')
proc = ctx.Process(target=SomeClass, kwargs={})
proc.daemon = True
proc.start()
```

it works with no problem. But how can I avoid the sys.path.insert or why does this happen? Is there a more elegant solution?